# Wrong table count in DbUnit + springtestdbunit

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, unit-testing, dbunit

I have 2 tables, but code from this post leads exception.

What I am doing wrong?

How fix this?

Fail text

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: table count
Expected :5
Actual   :2
```

Pom dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Dataset

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
<table name="CATEGORY">
    <column>CATEGORY_ID</column>
    <row>
        <value>1</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>2</value>
    </row>
</table>
<table name="CATEGORY_RELATIONS">
    <column>CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID</column>
    <column>CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID</column>
    <column>ID</column>
    <row>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
        <null/>
    </row>
</table>
</dataset>
```

POST UPDATE (information, requested by people added)

Test

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:data-sets/empty.xml")     
@ExpectedDatabase("classpath:data-sets/categories/save.xml") 
public void save() throws Exception { 
   testTarget.save(parentCategory); 
   testTarget.save(childCategory); 
}
```

empty.xml

```
<dataset> 
   <CATEGORY/> 
   <CATEGORY_RELATIONS/>
</dataset>
```

No table counters

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)     
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
   DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, 
   TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, 
   HSqlTestExecutionListener.class}) 
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:contexts/bean-locations.xml"}) 
public class SpringHsqlTest {//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset XML clearly shows two tables being created, presumably in a separate unit test database.

Your test code seems to be expecting 2 tables, but it seems that 5 exist - let's see if we can confirm that.

I presume the testTarget object in your save() test method is a Spring repository of some kind. So you should be able to add the following to that repository:

`@Query(value = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='TABLE' ", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> tableNames();`

then in the save() method in the test:

`for (String table : testTarget.tableNames()) {
    System.out.println(table);
}`

this should cause the list of tables the test method has access to to be printed on the console.

Comment: Other tests are going well, but with such xml structure: "<dataset>
    <CATEGORY/>
    <CATEGORY_RELATIONS/>
</dataset>". I have only one database.

Comment: Ok, can you post the code of the testcase that's failing? Presumably you have some code that is counting the number of tables, and you're passing the expected number (which seems to be 5 based on the output) and the actual number (which seems to be 2 based on the output) to an assertion?

Comment: `@Test
    @DatabaseSetup("classpath:data-sets/empty.xml")
    @ExpectedDatabase("classpath:data-sets/categories/save.xml")
    public void save() throws Exception {
        testTarget.save(parentCategory);
        testTarget.save(childCategory);
    }`

Comment: empty.xml `<dataset>
    <CATEGORY/>
    <CATEGORY_RELATIONS/>
</dataset>`

Comment: No table counters `@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        HSqlTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:contexts/bean-locations.xml"})
public class SpringHsqlTest {`

Comment: Ok so presumably the Dataset XML you posted earlier is empty.xml ? Can you post save.xml as well.

Comment: save.xml is "Dataset" from the post. And thank you THOUSAND times!

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm assuming that (SpringTest)DBUnit isn't lying to us, and there really are 5 tables in the database, somehow. You seem to be using HSQL for these tests - in memory version? Perhaps you could post the JDBC URL. I'm thinking it might help if you could execute some SQL in the save() @Test method to list the table names in the database - let me check if/how that can be done in HSQL....

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you might list the actual tables the test can see.